# VueJS pass data between two pages

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

There are so much choices to pass data between to pages.
I want to make the same thing when you click on the title product https://crisgon.github.io/vue-cart/dist/?ref=madewithvuejs.com#/

Can you tell me what is the good way to pass JSON object to another page ?

- Should I use Vuex ?
- Should I emit a bus event ?
- Should I use LocalStorage ?
- Should I pass the ID in the route GET parameter then call API to retrieve my data ?

I'm so confused...

Answer (score 2):

The site is a SPA, when you click on an item the page does not reload, so the solution with the GET param is not the one the guys used. They most likely used https://router.vuejs.org/ to make this work. It's up to you whether you want to use vuex or just a plain object that you import in the component. Just be aware that you don't need to pass it between pages as you say. Inspect the product detail with the developer tools then you will get an idea of it. There is probably a ProductBox component that needs a path for the picture, a title etc. I would store these variables in a vuex store and make this component use them as computed properties, but this is up to you. Also consider that this is a demo and that the amount of products is likely to be a lot bigger on a real life shop and that the ProductBox will show details that are not already loaded on the start view. Then your solution with the API request is the right one, in order to keep it an SPA you have to call it by ajax. My choice for that is https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios
Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over thinking this. From what I can see from the example you posted, the expanded view of a product contains much the same data as the grid view. When the user clicks on a product they are taking to a new route in the app where the specific product details are presented.

There are a variety of ways you could achieve this, and I don't think you need state management to do it at all.

My preferred option would be to use a callback in the list item component that is triggered if the user clicks on the product title. The callback will update the state of the parent component which can then hide the list and present the detailed view of the product. Each list item component can be given a product ID as a prop, which is then passed back in the callback. So it might look something like:

```
For each list item:
<div class="title" onClick={productSelected(this.props.id)} > . 
     {this.props.productTitle}
</div>

When rendering the list:
<ul>
      { this.props.productIds.map((productId) => {
           return (
               <ListItem 
                   onSelected={this.props.productSelected}
                   id={productId}
               </ListItem>
           )
      {

In the parent component:

constructor(props) {
    super(props) 
    this.state = {
        selectedProductId: ""
    }

    this.productSelected = this.productSelected.bind(this)
}

this.productSelected(selectedProductId) {
    this.setState({selectedProductId})
}

...

render() {
     <div>
          { (this.state.selectedProductId !== "") ?
                 return ( <ListComponent 
                           productIds={[ ... ]} 
                           productSelected={this.productSelected}
                          >
                         )
            : return ( <DetailedProductOverview 
                         productId={this.state.selectedProductId}
                       >
                     )
          }
     </div>
}

....
```

*please note this is not supposed to be working code, rather a hint to a solution

So the idea is that the parent component will conditionally render either the list or a detailed view depending on whether the selectedProductId state variable has a value.

Hope that helps.